# ConditionalOnProperty - mock

Tags: java, spring, mocking, mockito, javabeans

I'm trying to prepare a class which will mock one of it's fields if a testing mode is enabled.

Here is the code:

```
@Configuration
public class StripeConfig {
    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "stripe", name = "service", havingValue = "mock")
    StripeCustomerService mockService() {
        return Mockito.mock(StripeCustomerService.class);
    }

}
```

And the service:

```
@Service
public class StripeCustomerService {

    @Value("${stripe.key.test.public}")
    private String stripeKey;

    @Autowired
    private StripeSubscriptionService stripeSubscriptionService;

}
```

Then I try to use it in my another service:

```
@Service
public class UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    private StripeCustomerService stripeCustomerService;
}
```

Unfortunately when I'm runing the code, it appears that no Mock is being used. `StripeCustomerService` is being injected.

Answer (score 2):

I see that you have `@Service` annotation on `StripeCustomerService.class`. So if you set value mock for `service` property, you will have two beans registered and the one named `stripeCustomerService` will be injected.

I reproduced it locally, but changed the configuration to only register one bean and it works fine.

Application.class

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    CommandLineRunner init(final StripeCustomerService stripeCustomerService) {
        return args -> {
            stripeCustomerService.call();
        };
    }

}
```

StripeCustomerService.class

```java
@Slf4j
public class StripeCustomerService {

    public void call() {
        log.info("{}", this.getClass().getName());
    }
}
```

StripeConfiguration.class

```java
@Configuration
@Slf4j
public class StripeConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnProperty(name="stripe.mock", havingValue = "true")
    StripeCustomerService mockStripeCustomerService(){
        final StripeCustomerService mock = Mockito.mock(StripeCustomerService.class);
        doAnswer(invocation -> {
            log.info("{}", mock.getClass().getName());
            return null;
        }).when(mock).call();
        return mock;
    };

    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnProperty(name="stripe.mock", havingValue = "false")
    StripeCustomerService stripeCustomerService(){
        return new StripeCustomerService();
    }

}
```

application.yml

```yaml
stripe:
  mock: ${STRIPE_MOCK:false}
```

For `false` value application will log:

```
2023-05-01 18:47:02.704  INFO 44596 --- [           main] io.stripe.Application                    : Started Application in 3.021 seconds (JVM running for 4.289)
2023-05-01 18:47:02.706  INFO 44596 --- [           main] io.stripe.StripeCustomerService          : io.stripe.StripeCustomerService
```

For `true` value application will log:

```
2023-05-01 18:50:39.055  INFO 45640 --- [           main] io.stripe.Application                    : Started Application in 3.05 seconds (JVM running for 4.181)
2023-05-01 18:50:39.061  INFO 45640 --- [           main] io.stripe.StripeConfiguration            : io.stripe.StripeCustomerService$$EnhancerByMockitoWithCGLIB$$7b52ce4a
```

Comment: If this answer best solved your issue, then consider marking it as correct to help guide others with the same issue in the future